# skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented' BitmapFactory fails to conver byte array int Bitmap object

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm using CameraView library to preview camera in my app. I want to scan the images from camera preview. But when I'm receiving camera preview images in the byte array, I'm unable to convert the byte array into Bitmap. Please assist.

Here is the method. This method executes asynchronously. Here byte has values but bitmap is null.

```
private void processFrame(Frame frame) {
    if (frame.getDataClass() == byte[].class) {
        byte[] data = frame.getData(); 
        Log.d("OnFrame", "bytes " + data.length);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
        Log.d("OnFrameSize", bitmap == null ? "null" : "non-null");
    }
}
```

Here is the log

```
2020-07-22 00:00:00.051 17521-18409/com.shabdkosh.android D/OnFrame: bytes 1382400
2020-07-22 00:00:00.184 17521-18409/com.shabdkosh.android D/skia: --- **Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'**
2020-07-22 00:00:00.184 17521-18409/com.shabdkosh.android D/OnFrameSize: null
```

Please help.